# Apply html tag for listing items based on values with jQuery and Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a message inbox. I would like to display each message in different background based on its read status (read/not read).

My @messages variable contain multiple messages, each of which has an attribute called read_at.

My question is: how do I apply class to these items dynamically based on their read status?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with rails like this

```
<% @messages.each do |m| %>
  <div class="<%= m.read_at.nil? ? "unread" : "read" %>">
    <%= m.message_body %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Then you can set the style for read/unread messages accordingly in your css file.

In case you're unfamiliar, this line `<%= m.read_at.nil? ? "unread" : "read" %>` is a ternary statement. This explains it pretty succinctly http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation#Ruby

Answer (score 1):

In your controller, loop through all the messages and check if it's been read or not.

```
@messages.each do |m|
    if m.read_at < DateTime.now
        m.status = "read"
    else
        m.status = "unread"
    end
end
```

Then when your listing your messages in HTML

```
<li class="<%= m.status.to_s %>">Blahblah</li>
```

Your CSS

```
.read { background-color: grey; }
.unread {background-color: yellow; }
```